# set expected result as true when find in a string partly correct protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

Hello everyone I got following code:

```
 it('Search for string', function () {
        var MySearch = element(by.model('searchQuery'));
        MySearch.sendKeys('Apple Pomace');
        expect(MySearch.getAttribute('value')).toBe('Apple Pomace');
        element(by.buttonText('Search')).click();
        //browser.pause();

      var optionTexts = element.all(by.repeater('product in products')).map(function (Options) {
            return Options.getText();
        });
        optionTexts.then(function (array){

            expect(array).toContain("Apple Pomace");

            });

        });
```

then I get as result:

```
[ 'Apple Pomace\nFinest pressings of apples. Allergy disclaimer: Might contain traces of worms. Can be sent back to us for recycling.\n0.89' ]
```

now I want to check if the string contains **Apple Pomace**

I have tried following code:

```
expect(array).toContain('Apple Pomace');
```

then I get:

```
Expected [ 'Apple Pomace
Finest pressings of apples. Allergy disclaimer: Might contain traces of worms. Can be sent back to us for recycling.
0.89' ] to contain 'Apple Pomace'. <Click to see difference>
```

how do I set the test to true even if the whole string doesn't match my result?

or validate the string to the first "\" ?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdwOQ.png)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all `element.all(by.repeater('product in products')).getText()` will return array of strings.If you use `toContain` matcher on the array, it will check for the whole string to be present in the array.

In your case, you need to check if the entire array has any string that matches the word `Apple Pomace`. To achieve this, you need to transform the result array into a string and then apply `toContain` matcher on it.

```
var displayedResults = element.all(by.repeater('product in products')).getText()
                      .then(function(resultArray){
                         return resultArray.join(); // will convert the array to string.
                       })
expect(displayedResults).toContain("Apple Pomace");
```

Hope this might help you!

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will try it!